# Is there any limit to the size of lines in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

We are generating some Javascript code with VBScript, and one of the JS line is :

```
document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "<div>...</div>";
```

Potentially, the content between `<div>...</div>` could be **big**. (> 100.000 characters)

We are afraid that, **for any reason** (JS specifications, browser specific limitations), there could be a limit to the size of lines in Javascript, which could then break the code. (Because it is a string, and not just some code. If it breaks in the middle of the string, it would result in a syntax error, right ?)

We noticed that jquery-x-x.min.js is split in 3-4 lines with line breaks, and we thought it could be because of such particular limits.

Of course, we could handle it that way :

```
.innerHTML = "<div>" +
             "..." +
             "</div>";
```

But with our current VBScript code, it would be really hard to do, and we'd like to stick to a single line if it is possible and safe. No need to suggest multi-line solutions.

So the question is :

**Is there any limitation to the size of lines in Javascript, considering IE 7+, FF and Chrome, that could break our long string and so, break the code ? Or are we safe that way, no matter how long the line becomes ?**

(All we could find so far was related to file size, stack size or syntax errors)

Comment: No, but there are better ways of doing that so it is maintainable.

Comment: `100.000` bytes is still a mere `100 kB`. Don't worry about it too much.

What should concern you, though, is that you're using strings that contain a load of HTML, and inserting it with `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Cerbrus There are some obscure reasons and constraints behind it. Be sure that we are concerned enough about it.

Comment: Don't listen to people. Not many people are aware that strings in JavaScript have a size restriction of `16777215` characters. If you have more RAM then perhaps it could be increased. Otherwise you would need to use part of your secondary storage device for extra memory. Problems can be caused due to swapping and virtual demand paging. Overall I would suggest that you don't use JavaScript at all. Visual Basic is a much better language. The name gives it away. It is visual and it is basic. It couldn't get any more simpler than that. Just stick to Visual Basic for all your programming needs. 3=)

Comment: @AaditMShah What do you mean by "strings in JS have a size restriction of 16.777.215 chars" ? You mean in memory or in the code itself ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet Neither. It was sarcasm. Both code and strings in JavaScript don't have any hard limits. You can write as much code or as long strings as you want and you won't ever have a problem on modern systems. As Cerbrus said, don't worry about it too much. Modern JavaScript engines can handle almost anything that you throw at them.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there aren't any hard limits on the amount of Javascript code that a browser will handle. I've never seen an issue caused by just having too much Javascript code. It's going to be more efficient to transfer a single file versus multiple files. As far as the order goes, that depends on how you define your functions.

You will have to determine whether the browser can handle that much code without balking. The whole idea of using functions is to break a task down into manageable code segments.You will probably need to break that code up so that it can be executed in sections.

Comment: This should really be a comment. Also how is using functions going to help in this case?